# Minimum answer c++

Tags: c++

I'm beginner, and trying to understand how to calculate a math function, and if the answer is below 0, set it to 0. I know I could use an if statement, but it seems like bad practice and I can't find if there's a better way to do it. I ask this because in visual basic there were min functions, I am curious if there is in c++.

Here's an example

```
int a = 5;
int b = -6;
int answer = a + b; 
//Answer would be -1 at this point.
if(answer < 0){answer = 0;}
```

Let me know if there is an easier way to do with, perhaps with a minimum value function.

**EDIT: Follow up, how would I do the max function with only 1 value? For example,
If I wanted to compare ANSWER to 0, instead of a, b and 0?**

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min/

Comment: I get pretty direct results googling "C++ minimum". [This page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) for example.

Comment: Or the tenary operator : http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/1AUq5Di1/

Comment: The if() statement is not obsolete.

Comment: Actually, the function you want is `max`, not `min`.

Comment: I don't know what the definition of "better" is, but my gut tells me there be more overhead in a function call then the code you posted. (few hoops you must jump through when calling a function which may contain nearly the same code as what you wrote in the first place). I think your way is certainly fast and easy to read to me

Comment: @donsiuch that doesnt need not be true, very probably the compiler will be able to inline

Comment: @Barmar, please don't link to cplusplus.com.

Comment: Sorry didn't know. Are they like w3fools?

Answer (score 11):

An equivalent declaration is

```
int a = 5;
int b = -6;
int answer = std::max( a + b, 0 );
```

Comment: To OP: don't forget to `#include <algorithm>` to be able to use `std::max`.

Answer (score 11):

You can do this a ton of different ways.  Here are a couple of the more straight-forward ways:

```
int answer1 = std::max(a + b, 0);
int answer2 = (a + b) < 0 ? 0 : (a + b);
int answer3 = (::abs(b) >= a && b < 0) ? 0 : (a + b);
```

Note that you do not actually want to use `std::min` for your problem, but rather `std::max`.

To answer your follow up question, it would look like this:

```
int answer4 = std::max(a, 0);
int answer5 = (a > 0) ? a : 0;
```

Comment: I wouldn't go with the second solution because you are making one expression two-times, which is not obviously slower (without optimalization) but also if use in conjucation with overloaded operatators it can be a lot of evil.

Comment: @Zaffy True, though, I would have thought the first solution was simple enough that it would have been the preferred solution anyway ;)

Answer (score 4):

That's pretty minimal. There's always "inline ifs":

```
int answer = a + b;
answer = answer < 0 ? 0 : answer;
```

I think you're code is better and more readible.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = 5;
int b = -6;
int answer;
```

You can go like this
    int answer = (a + b) < 0 > 0 : (a + b);

or you can use its equavalent

```
if( (a + b) < 0 )
   answer = 0;
else 
   answer = a + b;
```